# Unix: selecting lines based on column values - what is wrong with this for statement?

Tags: unix, for-loop

I am pretty new to bash commands, and I'm trying to make a for statement that prints out each line with a value of 3 in the 6th column (space delimited) to a file. My syntax looks like this:

```
for i in `cat test`
do
section=`echo ${i} | cut -d ' ' -f 6`
line=`echo ${i}`
if [ ${section} == "3" ];
then
echo ${line} > test.out
fi
done
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work... Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not reading the file the right way.

You can debug it by trying:

```
for i in `cat file.txt`
    echo $i
done
```

you will see that it prints each word on a new line, because the for-loop is actually iterating over each *word* in the file, instead of each *line*.

To read a file line by line use the following:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
     echo "$line"
done < file.txt
```

By the way, if you want an alternative solution, you can use this `awk` one-liner:

```
awk '$6 == "3"' test > test.out
```

Comment: That one-liner is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: So I tried to do this for several values (to make several files) in a for statement, but the for statement does not recognize the '$6 == "3"' if I replace the 3 with the variable that I vary with the for statement, like this: '$6 == "${i}"'. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: The `'` will prevent Bash's variables from being interpolated (`${i}`); using `"` will allow them in, but then you have to protect the Awk `$` from the shell, with something like `awk "\$6 == $i" test > test.out` (the `\` protects the `$` from the shell inside of `"`)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is actually

```
    `cat`
```

You're effectively reading the entire file, then pumping it into the `` operator, which splits on whitespace. So, you're *not* processing lines: you're processing "words," as the shell defines them, one at a time.

Try, instead, something like:

```
 ( while read line ; do
      section=`echo ${line} | cut -d ' ' -f 6`;
      if [ "${section}" == "3" ]; then
          echo ${line} > test.out;
      fi
   done ) < test
```